# JPQL, how query to find repeatation of objects per day?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-datastore, jpql

I have a trending application. The app gets list of trends from Tweeter every an hour and put it in data store (without checking for duplication based on name). Therefore, for a particular word such as "Thaipusam" I'll have so many objects that their only difference is `date` which has been calculated by `long date = new Date().getTime();` whenever background process want to push it to data store.

Each object is like this:

```
{
    id: 4749890231992320,
    name: "Thaipusam",
    url: "http://twitter.com/search?q=Thaipusam",
    query: "Thaipusam",
    location: "Kuala Lumpur",
    woeid: 1154781,
    date: 1389865326440
}
```

Since I have over 5000 objects in the datastore, I need to know how many times each object searched per day.

- What is the best/efficient practice to calculate/query repeatation per day?

Comment: Would the [Sharding counters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters?csw=1) approach help?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea it's the most efficient way or not but I did this in my servlet and result is satisfactory:

```
private static final long MILLIS_PER_DAY   = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
private static final long MILLIS_PER_WEEK  = 7 * MILLIS_PER_DAY;
private static final long MILLIS_PER_MONTH = 30 * MILLIS_PER_DAY;
private static final long MILLIS_PER_YEAR  = 365 * MILLIS_PER_DAY;
private static final String QUERY_PER_PERIOD = "SELECT m.date FROM TwitterTrendsJPA As m WHERE m.name = :keyword1 AND m.date >= :keyword2";
```

in doGet() method:

```
long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
long last24hours = currentTime - MILLIS_PER_DAY;
long last7days = currentTime - MILLIS_PER_WEEK;
long last30days = currentTime - MILLIS_PER_MONTH;
long last365days = currentTime - MILLIS_PER_YEAR;

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<Long> statList;
                Statistic statistic = new Statistic();

                Query query1 = em.createQuery(QUERY_PER_PERIOD);
                query1.setParameter("keyword1", p2);
                query1.setParameter("keyword2", last24hours);
                statList = (List<Long>) query1.getResultList();
                statistic.setPerDay(statList);

                Query query2 = em.createQuery(QUERY_PER_PERIOD);
                query2.setParameter("keyword1", p2);
                query2.setParameter("keyword2", last7days);
                statList = (List<Long>) query2.getResultList();
                statistic.setPerWeek(statList);

                Query query3 = em.createQuery(QUERY_PER_PERIOD);
                query3.setParameter("keyword1", p2);
                query3.setParameter("keyword2", last30days);
                statList = (List<Long>) query3.getResultList();
                statistic.setPerMonth(statList);

                Query query4 = em.createQuery(QUERY_PER_PERIOD);
                query4.setParameter("keyword1", p2);
                query4.setParameter("keyword2", last365days);
                statList = (List<Long>) query4.getResultList();
                statistic.setPerYear(statList);
```

and Statistic class is like this:

```
private final class Statistic {

        private List<Long> perDay;
        private List<Long> perWeek;
        private List<Long> perMonth;
        private List<Long> perYear;

        public List<Long> getPerDay() {
            return perDay;
        }

        public void setPerDay(List<Long> perDay) {
            this.perDay = perDay;
        }

        public List<Long> getPerWeek() {
            return perWeek;
        }

        public void setPerWeek(List<Long> perWeek) {
            this.perWeek = perWeek;
        }

        public List<Long> getPerMonth() {
            return perMonth;
        }

        public void setPerMonth(List<Long> perMonth) {
            this.perMonth = perMonth;
        }

        public List<Long> getPerYear() {
            return perYear;
        }

        public void setPerYear(List<Long> perYear) {
            this.perYear = perYear;
        }
    }
```